# Question with 2 subjects connected with "not only... but also..."

Tags: grammar, subject-verb-agreement

In case of "Not only . . . but also", the verb agrees with the second subject or the one that is nearest the verb:

> Not only I but also he is going to Japan.

However, I'm struggling with the question. When the question has 2 subjects connected with "not only... but also...", should I use the verb form of the second subject or the one that is nearest the verb?

Which one is grammatically correct?

> a) Are not only you but also he going to Japan?

> b) Is not only you but also he going to Japan?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Option (a) sounds way better, but a native speaker would do anything in his power to rephrase the question to avoid this problem.

Comment: I agree. A simple alternative that jumps to mind is *Is he going to Japan with you?*

Comment: Yes. I don't think the _not only...but also_ formula is often used in questions. "Are you really not only the writer but also the director?" would usually be arranged as "Are you really the writer AND the director?" or "...as well as the director?"

Comment: _Not only I but also he is going to Japan_ may be grammatically correct, but I find it _very_ unnatural. "Not only am I going to Japan, but he is too", or "he's coming too" if you will be travelling together.